# Export fbx - uncheck apply modifiers - but include mirror and array modifier? (High poly / low poly workflow question)

Tags: modifiers, mirror, .fbx

My question has to do with optimizing workflow when working with high poly to low poly.

**What I want:**
I want to use the same mesh as low poly and high poly. On the low poly, when exporting as fbx, I uncheck "apply modifiers" and on the high poly I apply modifiers. I then use both versions to bake textures in for example Substance Painter.
I've tried this and it works perfectly in some cases.

**My problem:**
For example, say I have a complicated staircase. There's a lot of meshes with array and mirror modifiers, as well as bevel, subdivision surface, and a few others.
If I use the "apply modifiers for high poly, don't for low poly" approach, I loose my arrays and mirrors.
To get around this, I can duplicate the meshes and apply the mirrors/arrays but it's destructive and if I want to change anything later I have to go back to a previous state.

**My questions:**
Is this even a good idea, or am I missing some other, better workflow?
If it is a good idea, is it possible to export as fbx and choose which modifiers to apply?

It's not a very big deal but I'd be happy if anyone has any input. Thanks in advance.
/Mikael

Comment: You can disable the `show_viewport` property on all e.g. subdivision modifiers to ignore them when exporting to fbx (even with 'apply modifiers' enabled). Select all objects, hold `Alt` and click the monitor icon on the modifier of the active object, this way all subdivision modifiers of all selected objects will be disabled for the export. Otherwise you'd have to use python to disable/enable that property for the low and high poly. Question is where you want to put the files and what's your general workflow...? Are you ok with a folder called 'bake' in your main folder to put both files?

Comment: @brockmann I had no idea you could alt click modifiers to do what you just said. That's a great tip and seems to solve my problems. Thanks a lot! :)